# Joomla 3 - insert custom field in article editor

Tags: customization, field, article, joomla3.0

I inserted a custom field in the article edit page in the administration - I changed two files:
In /administrator/components/com_content/models/forms/article.xml
I added a field subtitle

```
<field name="subtitle" type="text" label="Subtitle"
    description="Add a subtitle here" class="inputbox" size="30"
    required="true" />
```

and in administrator/components/com_content/views/article/tmpl/edit.php
I added

```
<?php echo $this->form->getLabel('subtitle'); ?>
<?php echo $this->form->getInput('subtitle'); ?
```

Now I've created my custom field. But I have to store the values in the database when I input and save something, how does it work? 
Can anybody help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you add a field to the #__content table, it will probably be saved automatically. However I would not do that. You never know what an update does and you don't want to loose data.

If you look at /administrator/components/com_content/controllers/article.php you find a function called `postSaveHook`. This is where you can process the data further. There you could store your subtitle into an own table.

Anyway, you would need to apply those changes after each Joomla update, as it's likely that those files are overwritten.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I didn't know that it is stored automatically.. I won't make an update :)

Answer (score 2):

I know the question is not recent, but as others may find it I think it is important to clarify something.

By extending the article's form xml in the way you describe, you are hacking the core files. This is bad practice and should be avoided. As Bakual explained, these changes are likeky to be overwritten with an update of Joomla.

Not updating Joomla when new Security updates are released is even worse - don't go there.

What you should have done is extending the article's form xml in a way that doesnt interfere with core files. This article given an example on how to go about this:  http://docs.joomla.org/Adding_custom_fields_to_the_article_component